# Run script only on button click in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

Iam new to JSP and i can't seem to figure out how to run code only when the user clicks on the button..here's my code:

$

```
<form action="list_computers.jsp" method="post">                


        Search:
<input type="text" name="FromTextBox1"/>

<input type="submit" value="Search it!" >
   <%

        String TheSearch = (String)request.getParameter("FromTextBox1"); 

        String GetIt = Searcher(TheSearch);

        out.println(GetIt);

   %>
</form>
```

The Searcher() is a function i declared above this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What this code does is calls the function Searcher() when the page loads, and consequently throws an exception.

Comment: [Please don't use scriptlets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use javascript to check for the onclick event here's a little example with JQuery

```
 $("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
      //do your thing
      // use event.preventDefault(); to stop submission if need
 });
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript. We are talking about jsp code.

Comment: sry for the delayed response. My bad about the answer not being about jsp, miss understood the question. But isn't it better to separate the client side logic from view building and use javascript that way it's also easily reusable.

Comment: You do want to separate the logic always. Having the some code in js and some in HTML is not however separating anything. Look at the MVC model. You want to have a JSP page with all the HTML and a controller with all the logic.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like

```
if (request.getParameter("submit") != null) {
// do work here
}
```

You also need to give a name to your button

```
<input type="submit" value="Search it!" name="submit">
```

When user clicks (or presses enter), `request['submit']` will be equal to `"Search it!"`

I highly recommend moving this logic to the top of the page or even better to a [controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: No problem. I am confused still about what you are asking. Doing JavaScript is not what your question was.